# group by function in neo4j?

Tags: group-by, neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH(b:Book)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cu:Customer)-[pu:PURCHASED]->(:Order)-[]->(b)
RETURN pu.ISBN,SUM(pu.qty) AS quantity
```

I want to return the number of copies of each book sold – unsold books should show as 0 sold copies
this query does not return the correct answer, I just want to find a way to make a left join from the book node and then group the result by ISBN number. please help

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the `copies` field in `Book`?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `ISBN` property of `PURCHASED` relationship  so it will only show when the book is purchased by at least one customer. You should change it to use `Book`'s `ISBN` property:

```
MATCH(b:Book)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cu:Customer)-[pu:PURCHASED]->(:Order)-[]->(b)
RETURN b.ISBN, SUM(pu.qty) AS quantity
```

Comment: this does not return the correct value, it does the job but it is grouping in some weird way, that does not match the correct number of sold books

Comment: Could you share  more details? Include expected output, the output you are getting with this query?

Comment: MATCH (cu:Customer)-[pu:PURCHASED]->(:Order)
MATCH(b:Book)
WITH SUM(pu.qty) AS calculate,b, pu
RETURN b.ISBN,SUM(CASE WHEN b.ISBN =pu.ISBN THEN calculate ELSE 0 END ) AS quantity
ORDER BY quantity DESC

Comment: if I am using this script here I am getting the correct output which is : a table consists of the ISBN number and the sum of all sold books, and I want to achieve the same using optional match